# python, access references to variables made outside of module

Tags: python, module, scope

I have made a module called window that allows students to make an extremely simple GUI.

For example, the following code will make a button appear with the given text. Action is run when the button is clicked.

```
from window import*

button1 = button("this is my button")

def action():
     button1.text("this button has been clicked")

button1.clicked(action)

start()
```

I would like all of the variables students make to be made global by the module.
so that instead of writing

```
clicked = 0
button1 = button("this is my button")

def action():
     global clicked
     clicked = clicked + 1
     button1.text("this button has been clicked " + clicked + "times")

button1.clicked(action)
```

They are able to write

```
clicked = 0
button1 = button("this is my button")

def action():
     clicked = clicked + 1
     button1.text("this button has been clicked " + clicked + "times")

button1.clicked(action)
```

I apprieciate that this is the antithesis of python and so want to justify my position as this may seem pointless to the proffessional. I am teaching very young kids. Every line of code which does something beyond the scope of the learning objectives is a barrier. Teaching 10 classes of 30 kids 1 hour week means every obstacle removed will help a significant amount of children learn what I actually want them to learn.

I know this may seem silly, as a teacher I hope you can give me the benefit of the doubt in the significance of removing this line of code.

Within my module, I would like to be able to write something that finds the variables declared in the importing code and then add them to the globals of the importing code. Something like..

```
def start():
    a = something_that_finds_variables_declared_outside_of_module_scope()
    globals_of_importing_code().update(a)
    window_source.mainloop()
```

I also thought about overloading the assignment operator so when the students used it it automatically made the variables global, but this is impossible.

Comment: I'm assuming you meant the `global` statement to be within the function in the example? And I don't think this can be done like you want it to be. The variables within the function are classified ahead of time as either local or global by the compiler. You would need something that rewrites bytecode. That's potentially *possible*, but not likely easy.

Comment: I don't think you understand how globals work in Python. `clicked = 0` is global because it's defined in the global scope, not because it was preceded by a meaning `global clicked` statement. Inside `action`, assignment to the name `clicked` creates a local variable *unless* `global clicked` appears inside `action` to change the target of the assignment. This isn't something you can change.

Comment: You can't overload the assignment operator, because there *is* no assignment operator. Python has a dedicated assignment *statement* that's part of the grammar. (OK, there *is* an assignment operator `:=` for use in assignment expressions, but that's not overloadable either and is defined in a way that you *can't* use assignment expressions in place of assignment statements and vice versa.)

Comment: As @Carcigenicate says, this is possible to do by rewriting bytecode. For more information, check out https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html which has documentation on the bytecode structure. You'd have to call your modification code on the function. Some things you'll have to change include turning `STORE_NAME` and `STORE_FAST` into `STORE_GLOBAL`, `LOAD_NAME` and `LOAD_FAST` into `LOAD_GLOBAL` in the `co_code` bytestring. This won't be very easy though, and may also require manipulation of both `co_names` and the operands for these opcodes, as well as other unanticipated problems.

Answer (score 1):

The main issue is that you've entered a new scope where it would not be possible without using `global` or `nonlocal` for Python to determine that you want to assign to a value from the outer scope rather than making a new local scoped variable.

Doing anything magic to the code, like having it rewrite locals or globals is just going to make things more confusing when you move on to new projects that aren't using this framework.

If you want to just get rid of the `global` statement, how about assigning clicked as an attribute on the button? Because you are not assigning `button1`, you avoid the scoping issue for the assignment. This might be more understandable for your students, and might be an easier way to ease them into variable scoping without introducing `global` or `nonlocal` keywords yet.

```
button1 = button("this is my button")
button1.clicked = 0

def action():
     button1.clicked = button1.clicked + 1
     button1.text("this button has been clicked " + button1.clicked + "times")
```

---

Now for the awful hack to do this which **you should absolutely not implement**. I am only posting this for educational purposes. **You will confuse everyone doing this**.

Say you have the source code `test.py`:

```
count = 1

def foo():
    count += 1
```

You can use `inspect.getsource` to get a text representation of the function and then you can transform the function into statements by stripping off the method signature and un-indenting the code using `textwrap.dedent`.

Now that we have statements to execute, we can `exec` to call the statements while also replacing the locals with the `vars` of the module.

Note, this will only work with a very limited set of functions, and I made the assumption that the function signature is only ever declared on one line.

```
import inspect
import textwrap

def call_inline(func, local_vars):
    source = inspect.getsource(func)
    source = textwrap.dedent(source[source.index("\n"):]).strip()

    exec(source, {}, local_vars)
```

```
import test
call_inline(test.foo, vars(test))
print(test.count)
```

```
2
```

Again **DON'T DO THIS**

Comment: Thanks flakes. The issue of moving onto other projects is not really an issue. This is for introducing the concepts of logic and written code to students who will mostly not go on to learn any more coding. As strange as it seems, local and global is not understood by most students until they are 17 or older. This is for 12 year olds. However, I think that the suggestion that you have made is a sensible one. I might even make a container class called vaiables which is just used for holding their variables. e.g. variables.clicked = 0

Comment: @ecope A container object like you suggest sounds much more suitable.

Comment: While this solution works for non-indented functions (and _maybe_ some subsets of indented functions, though none immediately come to mind), bytecode manipulation poses a likely solution, albeit a tremendously painful one. I'll post a separate answer, but this is a very good answer too.

Comment: @Mous This will work for indented functions (which I assume you mean like while/for loops and if statements), just not for anything that creates new scopes themselves (like by calling to other functions or declaring and calling nested functions). Python is function scoped, not block scoped, so you don't have this problem in places where you might in other languages.

Comment: I stand corrected! Many thanks, I learnt something today

Answer (score 1):

Flakes has posted a very elegant solution which works for the subset of functions that you describe in the question. To make this work for all functions, a different approach will be required.

Note that this answer assumes some measure of understanding of Python and, as with Flakes' answer, is for educational purposes only.

#### High-level overview

Our goal is to intercept the function and modify it so that anything referencing local variables references global variables.

As a quick summary for people reading this answer who aren't familiar with Python's internals, Python "compiles" Python programs into bytecode, which is then interpreted. Bytecode is comprised of two-byte operator-operand pairs, and effectively acts as the code for a stack-based virtual machine.

#### Plan of attack

This is likely possible by decorating the function with a decorator that manipulates the `__code__` of the function and then uses this to reconstruct a modified function.

The basic task is replacing opcodes which reference or modify the locals with their global counterparts.

However, this requires a considerable amount of manipulation not just of the bytecode, but also of the various other attributes that CodeObjects possess.

#### Opcodes

##### Storage-related opcodes

These opcodes are used to take data off the stack and assign it to names.

###### Local variables

`STORE_LOCAL` takes a name index in `co_names` and assigns the TOS (top-of-stack value) to `co_names[namei]` in the local scope.
`STORE_FAST` takes a `var_num` (which is just jargon for a name index) in `co_varnames` and assigns the `co_varnames[var_num]` in the local scope.

###### Globals

`STORE_GLOBAL` takes a name index in `co_names` and assigns the TOS to `co_names[namei]` in the global scope.

###### Conversion:

`STORE_LOCAL` to `STORE_GLOBAL` conversion is straightforward - just replace the operand and leave the opcode and other `__code__` attributes untouched. `STORE_FAST` conversion is more difficult. You will need to modify `co_names` to include the names from `co_varnames`. If they were being selectively transferred over, this would be more difficult, but in this case you can just append `co_varnames` to `co_names` and leave `co_varnames` empty. This means that the operand will have to be changed from `var_num` to `len(co_names) + var_num`.

##### Deletion-related opcodes

This opcode is used to delete names.

###### Locals

The only deletion-related opcode is `DELETE_NAME`, which takes a name index in `co_names` and deletes `co_names[namei]` in the local scope.

###### Globals

`DELETE_GLOBAL` is like `DELETE_NAME` except it works in the global scope instead of the local scope.

###### Conversion

The conversion here is almost identical to that from `STORE_NAME` to `STORE_FAST`, with the exception that it is changing `DELETE_NAME` to `DELETE_GLOBAL`. The operand also remains unchanged.

##### Loading opcodes

These opcodes access things and push them to the stack.

###### Locals

`LOAD_NAME` and `LOAD_FAST` work exactly as their counterparts `STORE_NAME` and `STORE_FAST`, but in reverse - instead of popping the TOS and assigning it to the name, they push a reference to the name to the stack.

###### Globals

`LOAD_GLOBAL` is a bit more fiddly, having been changed in 3.11. It takes a name index like `LOAD_NAME`, but it then checks if the least significant bit of `co_names[namei]` is one, and if it is, pushes `NULL` to the stack. It then pushes `co_names[namei>>1]` to the stack regardless of whether the previous occurred.

###### Conversion

Luckily for us, `LOAD_NAME` never pushes `NULL` to the stack, so the conversion to `LOAD_GLOBAL` is as simple as changing the opcode to `LOAD_GLOBAL` and then changing the operand to the previous operand shifted one bit to the left. Since we've already decided on our process of combining `co_varnames` into `co_names`, converting `LOAD_FAST` is made a bit easier. We change the operator to `LOAD_GLOBAL`, and then change the operand to `len(co_names) + namei << 1`.

## Process outline

```
from types import FunctionType # or do FunctionType = type(lambda:0), they're equivalent

def transform(f):
    # get old attributes
    code = f.__code__
    co_names, co_varnames, co_code = f.co_names, f.co_varnames, f.co_code

    # construct new attributes
    new_co_names = co_names + co_varnames
    new_co_varnames = ()
    new_co_code = b''
    
    # iterate through co_code, finding instances of STORE_LOCAL, STORE_FAST, DELETE_NAME, LOAD_NAME and LOAD_FAST and rebuilding co_code in new_co_code
    # omitted because programming this would be a nightmare to end all nightmares
    
    # pass the attributes to CodeType
    new_code = code.replace(co_names = new_co_names, co_varnames = new_co_varnames, co_names = new_co_names) # there's probably more things that need changing - maybe co_cellvars too?
    
    # instantiate a new function and return it
    return FunctionType(new_code, globals())
```

#### Anticipated difficulties

1. Python 3.11 introduced a new `CACHE` opcode. I haven't looked into it in detail but apparently it's caused some difficulty for people manipulating bytecode.
2. There are several processes here that can cause operands to increase over 255, such as the fact that the combined co_names and co_varnames may roll over (modulo 255). This can be resolved by prepending `EXTENDED_ARG` as needed, but that also introduces more difficulties - instructions that involve jumping and looping will have to have their operands modified... which may lead to more `EXTENDED_ARG` opcodes, which means the jumps have to be modified. This process isn't endless but it's painful and you'll have to keep a running counter of how many bytes you've added, as well as dealing with edge cases where jump arguments themselves roll over.